# DocumentDB querying child elements in a document

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

In the DocumentDB document below, what's the correct way to query on the DevicePin? ie WHERE DevicePin = '1234'
I'm using Node.js and have the basic query working, I can query on things like Email and Name, just can't get the syntax for the DevicePin correct

```
{
    "id": "2ca572d0-858d-4376-8537-c228a8379638",
    "Email": "dave@test.com",
    "Name": "dave",
    "OrgRoles": null,
    "DeviceIDs": [
        {
            "DeviceID": "12121212",
            "DevicePin": "1234"
        }
    ],
    "UpdatedDate": "2017-11-10T13:18:32.0110724Z",
    "CreatedDate": "2017-11-10T13:18:27.220764Z",
    "IsDeleted": true,
    "_rid": "kIddAMqgTQBFAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/kIddAA==/colls/kIddAMqgTQA=/docs/kIddAMqgTQBFAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"02007530-0000-0000-0000-5a0d685b0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1510828123
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, in case anyone else is looking to do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM c.DeviceIDs[0] d 
WHERE (d.DevicePin = "1234")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the array element number then you can use

```
 SELECT * FROM c WHERE 
    array_contains(c.DeviceIDs, {"DevicePin": "1234"})
```